# boost timer error in c++ in windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, boost

I have installed eclipse IDE C\C++. When I compile my project I get the following error.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
fatal error: boost/timer/timer.hpp: No such file or directory   matrix_matrix_multiply.cpp  /Class Examples line 16 C/C++ Problem

The code is as follows. Please guide me how I can fix it.

Thanks,
Afshin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#include <vector>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
using namespace std;

void experiment(std::vector<double> &myVector) {
    // Computing L2 norm squared
    double normSq(0);
    double wallClockTime1;
    double total(0); //fake variable
    for (int add = 1; add <= 256; add = add * 2) {
        normSq = 0;
        boost::timer::cpu_timer timer;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i = i + add) {
            normSq += myVector[i] * myVector[i];
        }
        boost::timer::cpu_times elapsed = timer.elapsed();
        if (add == 1) {
            wallClockTime1 = elapsed.wall / 1e9; // we save how long it took if we use every coordinate
        }

        //we print how long it took to compute the sum of squares if we take only each  "add" coordinate
        cout <<"for add = "<< add << " took " << elapsed.wall / 1e9
                <<" was "<< wallClockTime1 / (elapsed.wall / 1e9) << "times faster "
          << endl;
        total += normSq;
    }
    cout << total << endl;
}

int main() {

    /* initialize random seed: */
    srand(time(NULL));
    // generate random vector
    std::vector<double> myVector(100000000); //allocate vector of size 100000000 doubles
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
        myVector[i] = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 0.0); //set each coordinate to a random number
    }

    experiment(myVector); //run experiment

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, we don't have "your project", so how can we possibly know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you set boost.include dir path correctly?

Comment: @Chad
Here is the code.

Comment: That is not related to the code. It seems to be related to the linking and include-dir

Comment: @MostafaTalebi
How I can solve it?

Comment: try downloading and install latest boost tar , looks like timer.hpp is missing

Comment: @zahidullah
I've installed 1.58 version. After adding the root address to g++ library in the project properties, this error is resolved. but there are some  other errors.

Comment: @zahidullah The errors are: <make: *** [normWithOffset.o] Error 1               > and           <recipe for target 'normWithOffset.o' failed>

Comment: please post error in detail , or share screen